# How to list all the tables created by an account in AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am wondering if there is a table or a query to list all the tables created by a certain user? I looked around redshift system tables but I couldn't find one yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL 8 queries will usually work in Redshift. You can do this:

```
select * from pg_catalog.pg_tables where tableowner='certainuser';
```